# Run-time error '9' if I open another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook in which I am running some VBA code successfully. However, if I leave this workbook open in the background and then open a second workbook to work on something else, the code in first workbook stops running and I get a "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range" message.

Does anyone know why this might be occurring? I am a real novice (I only began delving into VBA this week!) but suspect it might be because my code perhaps refers to the 'active' workbook and is therefore now trying to run on the second workbook I opened. This is the main 'module' code I am using:

```
Sub Auto_Open()

Call CopyValues

End Sub

    Sub CopyValues()

    Dim RowNo As Long
RowNo = Sheets(4).Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Sheets(4).Cells(RowNo, 2) = Sheets(1).Cells(14, 2)
    Sheets(4).Cells(RowNo, 3) = Sheets(1).Cells(14, 3)
    Sheets(4).Cells(RowNo, 4) = Sheets(1).Cells(14, 4)
    Sheets(4).Cells(RowNo, 5) = Sheets(1).Cells(15, 2)
    Sheets(4).Cells(RowNo, 6) = Sheets(1).Cells(15, 3)
    Sheets(4).Cells(RowNo, 7) = Sheets(1).Cells(15, 4)
    Sheets(4).Cells(RowNo, 8) = Sheets(1).Cells(16, 2)
    Sheets(4).Cells(RowNo, 9) = Sheets(1).Cells(16, 3)
    Sheets(4).Cells(RowNo, 10) = Sheets(1).Cells(16, 4)
    Sheets(4).Cells(RowNo, 11) = Sheets(1).Cells(17, 2)

If RowNo > 1440 Then
     Rows("2:2").Delete Shift:=xlUp
End If

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "CopyValues"

End Sub
```

I am also running this on the workbook:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim z As Integer
    z = 1440

    Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A2:K" & z).Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```

And this on 'Sheet4':

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 Or Target.Column > 11 Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Cells(Target.Row, 1) = Now
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: When working with more than one workbook it is best to fully qualify your references, so instead of `Worksheets("Sheet4")` you could write it like `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")`

Comment: Furthermore, instead of using `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")` you could use the Sheet Object Name which you can find underneath `Microsoft Excel Objects` in the VBA Editor. e.g. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Range...` would be `Sheet4.Range...`. Any code inside the sheet object, the sheet can be referred to using `Me`

Comment: Also `Rows("2:2").Delete` does not specify on which sheet you like to delete row 2 so Excel makes a guess and probably fails here. Another thing is that you use `Sheets(4)` which means the 4th sheet so if you re-order them another sheet is the 4th sheet. It's often more stable to use names like `Worksheets("Sheet4")` which does not depend on the order number but only on its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as @Xabier mentions, you're not fully qualifying your ranges. You can also create a loop to copy your data as there is a pattern there.

---

In `CopyValues()`, replace

```
RowNo = Sheets(4).Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Sheets(4).Cells(RowNo, 2) = Sheets(1).Cells(14, 2)
Sheets(4).Cells(RowNo, 3) = Sheets(1).Cells(14, 3)
Sheets(4).Cells(RowNo, 4) = Sheets(1).Cells(14, 4)
Sheets(4).Cells(RowNo, 5) = Sheets(1).Cells(15, 2)
Sheets(4).Cells(RowNo, 6) = Sheets(1).Cells(15, 3)
Sheets(4).Cells(RowNo, 7) = Sheets(1).Cells(15, 4)
Sheets(4).Cells(RowNo, 8) = Sheets(1).Cells(16, 2)
Sheets(4).Cells(RowNo, 9) = Sheets(1).Cells(16, 3)
Sheets(4).Cells(RowNo, 10) = Sheets(1).Cells(16, 4)
Sheets(4).Cells(RowNo, 11) = Sheets(1).Cells(17, 2)
If RowNo > 1440 Then
    Rows("2:2").Delete Shift:=xlUp
End If
```

with the following:

```
With ThisWorkbook
    RowNo = .Sheets(4).Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    For t = 2 To 11
        .Sheets(4).Cells(RowNo, t) = .Sheets(1).Cells(((t - 2) \ 3) + 14, 2 + ((t - 2) Mod 3))
    Next
    If RowNo > 1440 Then .Rows("2:2").Delete Shift:=xlUp
End With
```

---

in the `BeforeClose()` replace:

```
Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A2:K" & z).Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

with

```
ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A2:K" & z).Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

---

Lastly, for `Worksheet_Change`, as it's in a Sheet, you just need to change

```
Cells(Target.Row, 1) = Now
```

to:

```
Me.Cells(Target.Row, 1) = Now
```

Comment: Thank you - that seems to have worked. However, I did have to change .Rows("2:2") to Rows("2:2")

Comment: Sorry, missed the Sheet reference. Are those rows on Sheet1 or Sheet4?

Comment: You should change it to: `.Sheets(1).Rows("2:2")` or `.Sheets(4).Rows("2:2")` - depending on which sheet it is. But it should start with a `.`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this. You will need to check your sheet names in the VBA Editor match. Doing it this way will ensure that you're targeting the correct sheet (even if someone changes the sheet name in the front end)

```
Sub Auto_Open()
    Call CopyValues
End Sub

Sub CopyValues()
    Dim RowNo As Long

    With Sheet4
        RowNo = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        .Cells(RowNo, 2) = Sheet1.Cells(14, 2)
        .Cells(RowNo, 3) = Sheet1.Cells(14, 3)
        .Cells(RowNo, 4) = Sheet1.Cells(14, 4)
        .Cells(RowNo, 5) = Sheet1.Cells(15, 2)
        .Cells(RowNo, 6) = Sheet1.Cells(15, 3)
        .Cells(RowNo, 7) = Sheet1.Cells(15, 4)
        .Cells(RowNo, 8) = Sheet1.Cells(16, 2)
        .Cells(RowNo, 9) = Sheet1.Cells(16, 3)
        .Cells(RowNo, 10) = Sheet1.Cells(16, 4)
        .Cells(RowNo, 11) = Sheet1.Cells(17, 2)

        If RowNo > 1440 Then
             .Rows("2:2").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If

        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "CopyValues"
    End With
End Sub
```

---

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim z As Long
    z = 1440

    Sheet4.Range("A2:K" & z).Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 Or Target.Column > 11 Then Exit Sub
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        Me.Cells(Target.Row, 1) = Now
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: you're not fully qualifying `Sheet1` in `CopyValues`.

Comment: Where am I not? I'm referring to the Object name which is local to the workbook

Comment: Ah yes, I see that now. Didn't realise you could do it like that.